# How to wrap and stack items in QML, into rows and columns

Tags: grid, qml, grid-layout

I have a series of buttons that I want to appear in columns at the bottom of my QML page.  The number of columns across should depend on the width of the window, as the window width increases I want more columns to be added.  (And fewer rows as a result as components are pulled up to the previous line)

This is sort of like a Flow component, but I want the items to appear in columns, evenly spaced across the page, in rows and columns (columns centered vertically, at the bottom of the page).  Sort of like GridLayout.

I can't figure out what QML component(s) to use to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a GridView. See the [layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#gridview-layouts) documentation.

I'm not positive, but based on your description I think you would just need to set the `flow` property to `GridView.FlowTopToBottom`.